# Mongo data is not synced to Elasticsearch unless monstache is restarted

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, data-synchronization, monstache

`I am using Monstache 6.7.11, Elasticsearch 7.17 and Mongodb 4.0 version.

Unable to sync Mongodb data into elasticsearch untill we restarted monstache.

```
Below is my monstache.toml file

mongo-url = "mongodb://localhost:27017"

elasticsearch-urls = ["http://localhost:9200"]

elasticsearch-max-conns = 100

replay = true

resume = true

resume-name = "andes"

resume-strategy = 1

config-database-name = "andes"

enable-oplog = false

direct-read-namespaces = ["andes.SS_AA_Test","andes.qmf__source","andes.qmf__dashboard"] 

change-stream-namespaces = ["andes.SS_AA_Test","andes.qmf__source","andes.qmf__dashboard"] 

index-as-update = true 

gzip = false

verbose = true 

cluster-name = 'andes'

exit-after-direct-reads = false

[[mapping]]
namespace = "andes.SS_AA_Test" 
index = "SS_AA" 

[[mapping]]
namespace = "andes.qmf__dashboard" 
index = "andes" 
[[mapping]]
namespace = "andes.qmf__message" 
index = "andes" 
[[mapping]]
namespace = "andes.qmf__notification" 
index = "andes" 
[[mapping]]
namespace = "andes.qmf__package" 
index = "andes" 
[[mapping]]
namespace = "andes.qmf__query" 
index = "andes" 
[[mapping]]
namespace = "andes.qmf__resource" 
index = "andes" 
[[mapping]]
namespace = "andes.qmf__schedule" 
index = "andes" 
[[mapping]]
namespace = "andes.qmf__slog" 
index = "andes"
[[mapping]]
namespace = "andes.qmf__source" 
index = "andes"
[[mapping]]
namespace = "andes.qmf__story" 
index = "andes"
[[mapping]]
namespace = "andes.qmf__subset" 
index = "andes"

[logs]
info = "C:/Users/dsureshbhirud/Desktop/Elasticsearch_7.17/Mon_longs/monstache/logs/info.log"
warn = "C:/Users/dsureshbhirud/Desktop/Elasticsearch_7.17/Mon_longs/monstache/logs/warn.log"
error = "C:/Users/dsureshbhirud/Desktop/Elasticsearch_7.17/Mon_longs/monstache/logs/error.log"
trace = "C:/Users/dsureshbhirud/Desktop/Elasticsearch_7.17/Mon_longs/monstache/logs/trace.log"
```

Any Suggestions how can I resolve this issue

Thanks

Tried change-stream-namespaces and other monstache configurations.

Expectation:- Monstache should sync data from mongodb to elasticsearch without restarting monstache
`

Answer (score 0):

try "/opt/monstache/build/linux-amd64/monstache -f /opt/monstache/mongo-elastic.toml &" this command, this will allow monstache to run in background or use "nohup"
FYI This are for Unix-like systems.